# Geometry inconsistencies after computing intersection

Tags: r, r-sf

I am new to the geospatial side of things, and I am trying to partition a shapefile into grid pieces and then compute the intersection over the grid. However, I am running into consistency issues with the output. Here is a minimal example:

```
x <- st_read("https://data.sfgov.org/api/geospatial/rarb-5ahf?method=export&format=GeoJSON")
grids <- grids <- sf::st_make_grid(x, n = 40)
int <- st_intersection(x, grids)
```

I (expectedly) get the following message:

> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar

Then running `st_area` gives the following output:

```
> sum(st_area(x))
600592318 m^2
> sum(st_area(int))
600594187 m^2
```

The intersection gained area. Depending on where I am in the world, it sometimes loses area.

The real-world scenario I am using this with involves a shapefile and raster containing the entire world projected into `longlat`. I also need my output in `longlat`.

Comment: This is telling you that `st_intersection` assumes that `crs` is **planar** but you are using `longlat`. Use `st_transform` and reproject it to metric coordinates. When you are done, then you can always transform it back to `longlat`.

Comment: I don't think these comments are correct. `st_area` on a feature with lat-long 4326 coordinates computes the spherical surface area, which means these two objects should have the same area. But I suspect the algorithm for computing area on a sphere of an irregular polygon is *approximate*, and what you are seeing is the tolerance of that approximation. I hypothesise that if you could densify your features (ie add more vertexes) you'd get a closer answer. Note that if you `st_difference` your two things you get an empty set. Its got to be an accumulating algorithmic tolerance.

Comment: @Spacedman Actually, in my real-world example I _do_ get an `st_difference`. It is slight, however, and does not account for the entire area difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment by @Spacedman seems to be correct. You can test by densifying the polygons using function `densify` in package `smoothr`:

```r
library(sf)
library(smoothr)

x <- st_read("https://data.sfgov.org/api/geospatial/rarb-5ahf?method=export&format=GeoJSON")
grids <- grids <- sf::st_make_grid(x, n = 40)
int <- st_intersection(x, grids)

#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant
#> throughout all geometries

sum(st_area(x))
#> 600592318 [m^2]
sum(st_area(int))
#> 600594187 [m^2]

grids_dense <- smoothr::densify(grids, n = 60)
x_dense     <- smoothr::densify(x, n = 60)
int_dense   <- st_intersection(x_dense, grids_dense)

#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant
#> throughout all geometries

sum(st_area(x_dense))
#> 600594404 [m^2]
sum(st_area(int_dense))
#> 600594404 [m^2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who answered. The `densify` solution did work, but was too computationally expensive on my end. I tried other libraries and found a solution with `rgeos`.

```
library(rgeos)
library(sf)

x <- sf::st_read("https://data.sfgov.org/api/geospatial/rarb-5ahf?method=export&format=GeoJSON")
grids <- sf::st_make_grid(x, n = 40)
int <- sf::st_intersection(x, grids)

> sum(st_area(x))
600592318 m^2
> sum(st_area(int))
600594187 m^2

> rgeos::gArea(sf::as_Spatial(x))
[1] 0.06140787
> rgeos::gArea(sf::as_Spatial(int))
[1] 0.06140787
```

This works for me as I mostly care about *proportion* of area.